# How to use xpath in xslt to navigate a xhtml file?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath, xhtml

is there any way how can i navigate a xhtml file usig xpath in xslt? So I have this xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<!--  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stili.css" />  -->   
    <script src="jsorari.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">XMLHTTPREQUEST</h1>
<!--<div id="div1"></div>-->
<!--   <p id="txt1"></p>  <p id="txt2"></p>-->

<select id="dega" onchange="changeddl1(this);"></select><br/><br/>

<select id="viti" onchange="changeddl2(this)"></select><br/>

<select id="paralel" name="Paralel"></select><br/>

<button type="button" name="btn" id="btn1" onclick="afishovlera()">Afisho</button>
        </div><br/><br/>

        <table id="afishim"></table>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Lets say I want to navigate to select with id=viti
How can i do this and what namespaces should I include to xhtml and xslt file , if there is a way to do it. Please help me.

This is full xslt file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Viti" select="//*[@id='viti']" />
    <xsl:variable name="Paraleli" select="//*[@id='paralel']" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <h2>Orari mesimor</h2>
      <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr bgcolor="#71F9FF">
          <th style="text-align:left">Lenda</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Tipi</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Pedagog</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Dita</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Klasa</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Ora</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Viti</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Paraleli</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="Orare/Orar">    
        <tr>
        <xsl:if test="Viti = $Viti and Paraleli = $Paraleli">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Lenda"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Tipi"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Pedagog"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Dita"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Klasa"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Ora"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Viti"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Paraleli"/></td>
        </tr>    
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>    
      </table>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='xsltorari.xsl'?>
<Orare>
<Orar>
  <Dega>Bachelor në "Teknologji Informacioni dhe komunikimi"</Dega>
  <Viti>2</Viti>
  <Paraleli>B1</Paraleli>
  <Lenda>Grafe dhe alogoritme</Lenda>
  <Tipi>seminar</Tipi>
  <Pedagog>N/A</Pedagog>
  <Dita>E Martë</Dita>
  <Klasa>Salla I1 (200 C)</Klasa>
  <Ora>17:00-18:00</Ora>
</Orar>
<Orar>
  <Dega>Bachelor në "Teknologji Informacioni dhe komunikimi"</Dega>
  <Viti>3</Viti>
  <Paraleli>A</Paraleli>
  <Lenda>Administrimi dhe siguria e sistemeve</Lenda>
  <Tipi>leksion</Tipi>
  <Pedagog>N/A</Pedagog>
  <Dita>E Hënë</Dita>
  <Klasa>KlasaD3</Klasa>
  <Ora>13:00-14:00</Ora>
</Orar>
```

I dont know why this code doesn't work. Please anyone help me.
I want to display xml file based on condition when Viti from xml is equal to $Viti from select. Please help me.

Comment: `Viti = $Viti` this implies that you compare the contents of the @id="viti" with the contents of an element named `Viti` relative to the current node, but in the xslt the current node is `/` which has no child named `Viti`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get to this element is `//*[@id='viti']`

Comment: I did as you said and put the value from the select to a global variable in xslt. Now when I get the value of variable to the xsl:if the output shows nothing. Why happens this can you help me please? If you want I can paste all xslt file here. Note: I put the select value like this: <xsl:variable name="Viti" select="//*[@id='viti']" /> is this the right way?

Comment: I will put all xslt file and a part of xml file

Comment: Your question now includes an XHTML file and an XML file, and an XSLT stylesheet that sometimes seems to be reading the XHTML and sometimes the XML. It's quite possible to have two different source documents for a single stylesheet, but you need to distinguish them...

Comment: I know I am asking too much, but how can I distinguish them? Please help me

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the way to learn a programming language. I'm too busy to give you a personal tutorial -- there's plenty of information available if you care to read it. Ask a specific question if you get stuck, but for getting started, you need to do some reading.